# Wget multiple FTP files without re-logging in on every file

Tags: wget, ftp

Lets say there's a ftp site with a bunch of files I want to download - ftp://ftp.example.com, and they allow for an "anonymous login" over FTP.

Suppose that ftp://ftp.example.com has

```
file1.zip, 
file2.zip, 
... ,
file100.zip
```

Also suppose that I have a list of the filepaths I want to download all in a bash variable like so:

```
paths="ftp://ftp.example.com/file1.zip ftp://ftp.example.com/file7.zip"
```

Is there a way to do `wget $paths` (i.e. download my list of two files) without having to see wget do for every file:

```
Connecting to ftp.example.com|10.10.10.10|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged In!
```

where wget logs in to the authenticates with the site once for every single file I download?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the source, nope. Wget will always close the connection at the end of each file for FTP. Honestly, I have no idea why. If you drop a mail on bug-wget@gnu.org, we'll try and help you out / fix the code in Wget for this case

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use plain old ftp.  Set up a stanza for ftp.example.com in your `~/.netrc` file:

```
machine ftp.example.com
  login ftp
  password anonymous
```

... ensure that the file is not readable by anyone else:

```
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
```

Then send `ftp` commands via a here-document to retrieve the files:

```
ftp ftp.example.com <<'EOF'
prompt
mget file*.zip
bye
EOF
```

Some ftp clients may support the `-i` option to disable prompting for `mget`, negating the need for the `prompt` command in the list.

Using this will establish a single ftp session for all of the file transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want tip number 9 on [this page.](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples)

Basically, download multiple files with wget -i,

```
$ cat > download-file-list.txt
URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4

$ wget-i download-file-list.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. Wget still displays the `... connected ... Logged In!` messages when I write file paths out to temp.txt then do `wget -i temp.txt`. I timed the difference for ~20 files transferred - results were 3 mins 3 seconds for just doing wget the way I had it, and 3 mins 10 seconds for doing wget with the external -i file.

Comment: After re-reading your initial question, I realized you want no output... did you try doing a `wget -q -nv -O /tmp/output.txt -i temp.txt  > /dev/null 2>&1`